# Problem using MAGMA (computer algebra system) and Mac OS X 11.* (Big Sur)

Tags: symbolic-math, macos-big-sur

This question relates to the MAGMA Computer Algebra System (not the Matrix Algebra on GPU library).

I have used MAGMA on Mac OSX for many years, but recently, I am experiencing crashes on code that previously worked fine.

My experiments lead me to suspect that it is a recent update to Mac OSX 11 (Big Sur) that is behind the problems. I have prepared a MWE of the problem and tested it on about 5 Macs, and it has failed only on the ones running Big Sur.

The problem occurs when I try to rapidly loop through the list of transitive groups available in Magma.

Here is the definition of a test function that simply creates each transitive group in turn, and then returns true.

```
function testDeg(deg)
  for i in [1..NumberOfTransitiveGroups(deg)] do
    g := TransitiveGroup(deg,i);
  end for;
  return true;
end function;
```

If I run this on, say, the transitive groups of degree 24, by calling

```
testDeg(24);
```

then after some number of groups, it crashes.

```
> testDeg(24);

testDeg(
    deg: 24
)
TransitiveGroup(
    d: 24,
    n: 1194
)
In file "/Applications/Magma/package/Group/GrpData/trngps.m", line 18, column
51:
>>     return TransitiveGroup(TransitiveGroupDatabase(d), n);
                                                     ^
Runtime error in 'TransitiveGroupDatabase': GetLibraryRoot() is set to
/Applications/Magma/libs but the file GetLibraryRoot()/data/TrnGps/trans.dat
either does not exist or cannot be read (Interrupted system call).
```

In this case, the crash occurred on group number 1194, but this number will be different if I re-run it.

The error message is claiming that a certain file does not exist or cannot be read.

However the file certainly *does* exist, because the previous 1193 iterations of the loop have each used the same file.

So somehow there is a problem with "Interrupted system call".

At moment, I am just trying to gather evidence about whether this problem really is directly related to Mac OSX 11. I have contacted the MAGMA developers and they do not have a Mac running Big Sur, so they can't do anything.

I would very much appreciate

- Any evidence from Mac MAGMA users about whether this simple test function crashes on your machine (and the OS that you are running)
- Any suggestions as to what might be causing the problem, and how to resolve it.

(This morning I just updated from OSX 11.1 to OSX 11.2 and the problem still remains)

Thanks in advance

Comment: My limited understanding is that Big Sur is significantly different from previous versions (how different, and in what way, I don't know), and from a brief perusal of a web search for "Big Sur software compatibility" I guess that you might or might not run into problems. Is there a way to tell Big Sur to run in a mode which emulates an older version? It is possible that recompiling Magma for Big Sur might change things (then again, might not), although I guess it is necessary for the developers to do that. You might get other ideas on apple.stackexchange.com or a Magma-specific forum.

Comment: @RobertDodier Good point, there seems to be no Magma forum, but there is definitely an Apple forum, which I should have used.

Comment: I looked for Magma user forums and the only thing I found is this: https://groups.google.com/a/icl.utk.edu/g/magma-user Hope this helps.

Comment: @RobertDodier Sadly, this is the forum for the "other" Magma, the one about matrix algebra on GPUs.

Comment: Oh, rats, you're right. I overlooked that in my enthusiasm.